# Gradle leaves java process after finishing ant invocation

Tags: ant, gradle

I am in the process of migrating to gradle one of our modules say **gradle-module**. That module has two dependencies that are currently build with ant say **ant-module-1** and **ant-module-2**

In my gradle-module build.gradle i have the following entries:

```
task packageAntModule1(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'antModule1.gradle'
    tasks = ['clean', 'package']
}

task packageAntModule2(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'antModule2.gradle'
    tasks = ['clean', 'package']
}

compileJava.dependsOn(['packageAntModule1', 'packageAntModule2'])
```

The two files antModule1.gradle and antModule2.gradle are as simple as:

```
antModule1.gradle:
ant.importBuild '../ant-module1/build.xml'

antModule2.gradle:2
ant.importBuild '../ant-module2/build.xml'
```

I can see in the logs as part of building gradle-module that ant-module1 targets get executed and then moving to building ant-module2. However this is crashing because a temporary file created while building ant-module1 cannot be deleted. Looking at the java processes I can see a java process open by the first ant invocation which still holds my temporary file (loading some custom ant tasks)

So my question is what would be a way to tell gradle to finish off the ant JVM after finishing executing the required targets.

Any other suggestion about how to resolve my two ant dependencies would also be appreciated. Pointing to a maven repository via artifactory or nexus is not an option as our ant builds do not use ivy which is in fact the main reason we are moving to gradle

On top of this after gradle build fails the java processes started by ant are still alive and you manually have to kill them.

Thank you in advance for your inputs

UPDATE to add gradle version

```
$gradle -version
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.4
------------------------------------------------------------
Build time:   2015-05-05 08:09:24 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     5c9c3bc20ca1c281ac7972643f1e2d190f2c943c

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
JVM:          1.8.0_40 (Oracle Corporation 25.40-b25)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Comment: How is the temp file being created in the ant task? I suspect that `flush()` and `close()` is not being called in a `finally` block

Comment: No it is not that. The file is not created by our custom ant task. The file is the jar that holds our custom ant tasks. Both ant-module1 and ant-module2 need access to some tasks in that jar. Our common build structure has a `<taskdef resource="tasks.properties">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${temp.dir}" includes="MyCustomTask.jar"/> ...`
When you do this MyCustomTask.jar is loaded in memory and the problem is that the first ant invocation does not free that file when is finished. Because of this it fails to copy MyCustomTask.jar on top of the already opened one.

Comment: Which version of gradle are you using? It sounds like you might be hitting [this issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3009?jql=text%20~%20%22antbuilder%20file%22) which was fixed in v1.12

Comment: Yes it sounds like my case but I am not sure how the fix was implemented. I have two ant invocations inside my gradle build and if I understood it well the `fireBuildFinished()` call is done at the end of the gradle build. If my assumption is right  then this will not help me instead. A much better fix would have been to `fireBuildFinished()` at the end of each ant invocation not at the end of the gradle build. This can be a serious issue when migrating complex ant builds to gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you move the `taskdef` such that it's declared inside the ant task? This way the classloader should be discarded each time it fires.

I'm assuming that the `taskdef` is defined at the root level and therefore the classloader is kept in memory the whole time that the ant model is in memory.

Another workaround might be to copy the jar to a temp location which is different for packageAntModule1 and packageAntModule2.

Comment: Thanks Lance. It does have the taskdef inside an ant target (I think this is what u meant when you said "inside the ant task"). ` <target name="-load-external-tasks" depends="-copy-custom-tasks">
        <taskdef ...` the copy-custom-tasks` is where it blows up. My work around was to delete and then copy over the custom task jars and have the failonerror flag set to false but this is not a nice solution at all.

Comment: I still believe it is a gradle problem not closing up the ant JVM after finising that ant invocation  but rather leaving it for the end of the full gradle build. You can see it by watching how java processes  get created and closed up as the gradle build evolves.

Comment: Ant is fully integrated into gradle and runs inside the gradle JVM so the ant JVM cannot be 'closed'. If you want ant to run in a separate JVM you could invokeant via an [exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) task. This would require ant to be installed on the build machine and you would loose all of the ant / gradle integration goodness.

Comment: This whole setup sounds a bit hacky. Why does the jar need to change halfway through? Why can't the jar be final by the time the `taskdef`(s) are created?

Comment: Not sure why are you saying is hacky. If you go back to my original question I have two build.xml files I need to run the “clean package” on. The jar is final and is never changed again as part of a package invocation even if multiple targets will depend on that `-load-external-tasks` target.  But because I run package on two modules is exactly like invoking `ant package` twice.  Of course I can put an extra uptodate check and that will address my issue.

Comment: But my question still stands: If my first `ant package` invocation is finished why the resource is not released. More than this if any of my `ant package` invocations fails and the gradle build finishes as a failure why the jar is still locked and I manually have to kill the extra java process to unlock it. I don't think this is normal

Comment: It does sound like there is an issue with AntBuilder not releasing locks, but it also sounds like there's a design issue. Can you refactor it such that the jar is built in it's own task? Then packageAntModule1 and packageAntModule2 could depend on the common task and you could make use of gradle's up-to-date checks to only build it once. Or maybe you could pass a differenr ${baseDir} for each ant process so they don't step on each other's toes

Comment: The jar it is build in its own task and in the old way when ant was building `gradle-module` as well it was only built once. Of course if you wanted to build 'ant-module-1' and 'ant-module-2' in separate ant sessions the jar was created once for each ant invocation. This is what is happening now with gradle calling ant twice. The only one difference is that gradle does not release the lock as a command prompt ant invocation does and the second invocation fails because of this.

Comment: My fix was preventing that jar from being built unnecessary even when separate ant calls by changing the ant build to check if the jar is there and up to date (newer than its code & resources). However I believe gradle should be fixed as sometimes it is not that easy as it was in my case and migrating a complex ant build to gradle will always need some interim ant + gradle mix ups. When your builds do more than just compile and jar (JMS providers/app servers/environment config, deploy, code-generate) is always a challenge and being able to reuse what you built in years is a natural expectation

Comment: Accepting your answer as our chat here convinced me that I can't fix from gradle and motivated me to implement the fix on the ant side. Hope other readers will find some value in this change of ideas. Again thanks for your inputs.